# Difference between relationship and relations?

Tags: grammar

Which is the correct statement?

> She has outstanding interpersonal relationship with the group?

or

> She has outstanding interpersonal relations with the group?

Comment: I would be careful about saying "she has...relations with the group".

Answer (score 0):

Neither are correct.

In the first example “relationship” and “group” are both singular, so the word “an” should appear between “has” and “outstanding”.

In the second example the plural word “relations” implies that “group” should be replaced with “members of the group” or perhaps “all members of the group”.